# Select module which is the have the comment with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, pom.xml

I want to select module which is the have the comment line .

```
<modules>
    <module>com.umut.web</module><!--auto-->
    <module>com.umut.oaservice</module>
    <module>com.umut.signaturephotoservice</module>
  </modules>
```

powershell code=

```
[string]$modules=""
foreach ($module in $xmlFile.project.modules.module) {

  Write-Output $module.'#comment'  

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are asking is how to find the `<module>` that actually has the comment element directly behind it in the xml, right?

In that case, here is something that might do it:

```
[xml]$xmlFile = @"
<project>
    <modules>
        <module>com.umut.web</module>
        <module>com.umut.oaservice</module><!--auto-->
        <module>com.umut.signaturephotoservice</module>
    </modules>
</project>
"@

foreach ($node in $xmlFile.project.modules.ChildNodes) {
    if ($node.NodeType -eq 'Comment') {
        # if this comment node following a childnode within 'modules' 
        if ($node.PreviousSibling) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'module'      = $node.PreviousSibling            # the module element (System.Xml.XmlElement object)
                'moduleText'  = $node.PreviousSibling.InnerText  # the text inside this module element
                'comment'     = $node                            # the comment element (System.Xml.XmlComment)
                'commentText' = $node.InnerText                  # the text inside the comment
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

It emits a PSCustomObject with four properties or nothing if the search did not yield any result.

> ```
> module moduleText         comment  commentText
> ------ ----------         -------  -----------
> module com.umut.oaservice #comment auto
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you went a level too far in your `foreach`.

What if you do:

```
[string]$modules=""
foreach ($module in $xmlFile.project.modules) {
Write-Output $module.'#comment'  
}
```

Comment: yes I see auto output now. But I need also the other value which is same line.
For this example I need to also <module>com.umut.web</module> this value

Comment: the problem i see is the `#comment` property is not linked to the line that the actual comment is on. [*frown*] i tried moving it to the 2nd line & it still shows as the one & only comment instead of the 2nd comment. that makes it seem you cannot use the XML stuff to connect the comment with the module it is supposed to be addressing.

Comment: Yeah I don't think I'm able to help you with this. I would suggest restructuring the document. Searching for properties and values is a lot simpler.